# バックグラウンドにあるとき周期的にタスクを動かす方法について

Tags: ios, swift

iOS8でアプリケーションがバックグラウンドモードに移行したあとも、周期的にタスクを動かしたいと思い、ドキュメントを見ながら以下のようなコードを書いてみました。しかし、思い通り動いてくれません。なにか見落としがあるのでしょうか。

以下、AppDelegate.swiftより抜粋。

```
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND,0)

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    println("did enter background")
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}

func myBackgroundTask() {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)
    println("this is back ground task")
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS7以上であればBackground Fetchを使うのがいいのではないかと思います。
参考：http://www.gaprot.jp/pickup/ios7/vol1/

Comment: なにかをFetchしたいわけではないので、ちょっと抵抗があります。 :-)

Answer (score 3):

`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`を使う必要があります。

参考: [Cocoaの日々: [iOS] バックグラウンド実行見本（Task Completion）](http://cocoadays.blogspot.jp/2011/04/ios-task-completion.html)

Comment: `application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName()`を追加したら動くようになりました。Thanks! (しかし、コメント欄でのコード引用の仕方がわからない...)

Comment: よかったです。
ですよね。`この書き方`はできますが、通常のコードは別途書く必要がありそうです。

Answer (score 3):

下記のコードでバックグラウンドで周期的動作をするようになりました。 ただし180秒までが限界です(iOS8の場合）。expirationHandlerは限界に達する６秒ほど前に呼び出されました。またexpirationHandlerで終了処理を行わないと、アプリケーション全体が終了してしまいます。

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    println("did enter background")
    application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName("myBgTask", expirationHandler: myExpiratonHandler)
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}

func myBackgroundTask() {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)
    println("this is back ground task")
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}

func myExpiratonHandler(){
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    println("Expiration handler called: \(self.bgTaskId)")
    application.endBackgroundTask(self.bgTaskId)
    self.bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
}
```

Comment: 現在、時々アプリがクラッシュする現象が出ています。expirationHandler　はちゃんと設定しないといけないのかもしれません。週末になったら調べます。

Comment: expirationHandler の中でちゃんと終了処理を行わないとダメなようです。`application.endBackgroundTask(taskid)`

Comment: なおかつiOS8では180秒がバックグラウンドタスクが動ける上限の模様です。

Comment: anonakaさん、「下記のコードで望みの動作をするようになりました」とありますが、どこまで問題が解決したのかもう少し詳細にシェアしてほしいと思います。質問文を再編集することも可能ですので、現在の状況をより詳しく反映されてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 了解です。いまいろいろ試しているので、お正月明けまで時間を下さい。

Comment: 回答を一部手直ししました。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: @anonaka コメントスレッドの中の相手に通知するには `@naota` のようにコメントに書く必要があります。回答の方は、私はよさそうだと思います。ついでながら、回答の左にあるチェックマークをクリックして緑にすると、質問のステータスを解決済みにできます。

Comment: @anonaka 詳細な情報を加えていだだきまして、ありがとうございます。以前よりよく状況がわかりました。

Comment: @naota、@ento
いろいろご教授どうもありがとうございました。今後共どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。